# Error rejecting block bigquery_options in Terraform Logging sink

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Hope someone might have encountered this before.

I am trying to set up a logging sink in GCP using Terraform, and for that I am defining a module to create my sinks. I am getting an error saying `Blocks of type "bigquery_options" are not expected here` but I can't see a reason why since the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/logging_organization_sink.html) says that should be the way to do it.

This is my code:

```
resource "google_logging_project_sink" "main" {
  name = var.name
  project = var.project_id
  destination = var.destination
  filter = var.filter
  unique_writer_identity = var.unique_writer_identity

  bigquery_options {
    use_partitioned_tables = var.use_partitioned_tables
  }
}
```

This is the error I am getting while trying to build this:

```
stackdriver_logs_sink/main.tf line 13, in resource "google_logging_project_sink" "main":
 bigquery_options{

 Blocks of type "bigquery_options" are not expected here
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you switch to [attribute syntax instead of block syntax](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-12.html#attributes-vs-blocks) here? So change `bigquery_options {` to `bigquery_options = {`.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I tried that. Sadly it didn't work, now I am getting an error saying that the attribute is not expected.

Comment: What version of the Google provider are you using?

Comment: The version is 2.20.2

Comment: That attribute wasn't added until `v3.3.0`. You need to upgrade.